# JavaScript GeoJson Parser

Tags: javascript, android

i have geojson data:

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "metadata":{
            "generated":1417015873000,
            11-26T14:33:40&endtime=2014-11-26T14:33:45",
            "title":"USGS Earthquakes",
            "status":200,
            "api":"1.0.13",
            "count":1
        },
    "features":
        [{
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":
                {
                    "mag":6.8,
                    "place":"160km NW of Kota Ternate, Indonesia",
                    "time":1417012423350,"updated":1417015584000,
                    "tz":480,
                    "url":"http://comcat.cr.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000t08w",
                    "detail":"http://comcat.cr.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=usb000t08w&format=geojson",
                    "felt":1,
                    "cdi":5,
                    "mmi":4.98,
                    "alert":"green",
                    "status":"reviewed",
                    "tsunami":1,
                    "sig":712,
                    "net":"us",
                    "code":"b000t08w",
                    "ids":",at00nfnhsd,pt14330000,usb000t08w,",
                    "sources":",at,pt,us,",
                    "types":",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,impact-link,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,",
                    "nst":null,
                    "dmin":1.45,
                    "rms":1.32,
                    "gap":37,
                    "magType":"mwb",
                    "type":"earthquake",
                    "title":"M 6.8 - 160km NW of Kota Ternate, Indonesia"
                },
                "geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[126.5456,1.9752,41.06]},
        "id":"usb000t08w"
        }]
```

}

how to parse value "title" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var geojson = JSON.parse(geojson_data);`

Turns the geojson string into an object, from there you can get whatever you values you want from it.

Edit: your json is invalid, where are you getting the data from? I cleaned it up, so you can call `JSON.parse` on it. However, it is not valid geojson, so I'd double check where you come up with the data. [This geojson validator might help](http://geojsonlint.com/).

```
 {
    "metadata": {
        "generated": 1417015873000,
        "11-26T14: 33: 40&endtime=2014-11-26T14: 33": 45,
        "title": "USGSEarthquakes",
        "status": 200,
        "api": "1.0.13",
        "count": 1
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "mag": 6.8,
                "place": "160km NW of Kota Ternate, Indonesia",
                "time": 1417012423350,
                "updated": 1417015584000,
                "tz": 480,
                "url": "http://comcat.cr.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000t08w",
                "detail": "http://comcat.cr.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=usb000t08w&format=geojson",
                "felt": 1,
                "cdi": 5,
                "mmi": 4.98,
                "alert": "green",
                "status": "reviewed",
                "tsunami": 1,
                "sig": 712,
                "net": "us",
                "code": "b000t08w",
                "ids": ",at00nfnhsd,pt14330000,usb000t08w,",
                "sources": ",at,pt,us,",
                "types": ",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,impact-link,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,",
                "nst": null,
                "dmin": 1.45,
                "rms": 1.32,
                "gap": 37,
                "magType": "mwb",
                "type": "earthquake",
                "title": "M 6.8 - 160km NW of Kota Ternate, Indonesia"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    126.5456,
                    1.9752,
                    41.06
                ]
            },
            "id": "usb000t08w"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ohh, these method looks like convert geojson data type to json type

Comment: it doesn't work, can you give complete a file to parse value type from my geojson data :)

Comment: I added to the answer. Again make sure to [validate the json](http://jsonlint.com/) string.

Comment: hey thank you , and finally my code works succesfully :v

Comment: please accept the answer if you think it was sufficient!